# jZebra text file printing

Tags: browser, printing

I am using jZebra applet to print a dynamic generated text file. But it seems, the browser cached the file and printing the same old contents even after file contents are changed. "applet.clear()" did not help me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty trick for forcing against caching is to simply put a JavaScript timestamp at the end of the URL.  This makes the URL *appear* unique to the web browser and works for me every time, especially for IE and should also correct your problem for Java.

If you have a URL, i.e.

```
var url = "http://foo.bar";
```

Change it to:

```
var url = "http://foo.bar?" +  new Date().getTime();
```

Since jZebra allows the file URL to be provided either as a parameter, or allows the contents of the file to be appended, you should probably specify how you're appending your file next time for better clarification.

-Tres